# Cannot make addition work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button that when clicked adds 200 to the value of the p tag. I have looked up my question and clicked on every result, to no avail.Please help. Whenever I click the button it either prints NaN(Not a Number) or 200200200200200 etc.. I need help so that instead of those 2 mess-ups, it adds 200 each time the button is clicked. (addition not concatenation) 
Here is my code:

```
<button onClick="addPoints()">Click to get points!</button>
<p id="counter"></p>



<script>
function addPoints(){
var id=document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = parseInt(adding);
var adding = id + 200;
}
```

There is probably a mess-up I am not aware of. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're assigning to `adding` *after* using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `adding` variable was assigned after it is used. This code works:

```
<button onClick="addPoints()">Click to get points!</button>
<p id="counter"></p>

<script>
function addPoints(){
     var x = document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML;
     document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = (isNaN(parseInt(x))?0:parseInt(x)) + 200;
}
</script>
```

What I did here is the function checks the value of the counter `<p>` tag. If the content is an integer >= 0, add 200. Otherwise, assign an initial value of 0 before adding 200 so that the contents are added and are not concatenated.

Comment: I took that and made it my code. It still said "NaN"

Comment: @Mattattack Look at my solution..You will get it easily. This solution is correct as well. Its just he combined several steps.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the variable adding in parseInt before actually creating it.  Try this:

```
function addPoints(){
   var id=document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML;
   var adding = id + 200;
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = parseInt(adding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the sequence of code

```
function addPoints(){

var adding = parseInt( document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML) + 200;
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =adding;
}
```

Comment: It won't work as initially innerHTML of #content empty string and parseInt gives NaN. SO you can't add 200 to NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function addPoints(){
  var sum=parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML);
  sum = isNaN(sum) ? 0 : sum;
  sum += 200;
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert id to number

```
function addPoints(){
  var id=document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = parseInt(adding);
  var adding = ((id*1) + 200);
  }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: "Whenever I click the button it either prints NaN(Not a Number) or 200200200200200" 

var adding = ((id*1) + 200) takes care of that.